# Steam CS:GO API grab users matchmaking/competitive rank

Tags: steam

Just as  the  title says. I've searched the documentation but can't find anything.

I have http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<>&steamid=76561198316646133

but it states nothing about matchmaking rank.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible at the moment.

Steamapi only shows data about the profile (and probably something about dota2?), but not about in game things. If you want to do this, you should set up a Node.js bot with the help of [this](https://github.com/joshuaferrara/node-csgo) resource, set up a database, which log data collected by your node.js bot.